# Selenium Java- Need to select & assert a number inside a text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario wherein i need to locate the Link "(3) Hidden Documents" on the webpage & then do an assert simultaneously to verify if the braces of that linktext have the number 3 in it

Below is the html code:
 (3) Hidden Documents

Comment: <a class="view_hidden_results" href="#excluded_documents_header"> (3) Hidden Documents  </a>

Answer (score 0):

Get the text & parse it as follows:

```
String hiddenDocumentsText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.view_hidden_results")).getText();

int totalHiddenDocuments = Integer.parseInteger(hiddenDocumentsText.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
```